# Can I take the average of a column on a different tab that is based on referencing another column of dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Tab 1

```
Date       |Score
01/01/2016 |4
04/01/2016 |4
01/02/2016 |13
02/02/2016 |18
01/03/2016 |4
06/03/2016 |2
12/03/2016 |3
```

I want to search through the entire Date column to output the average of the score column, but on a different tab

I've tried:

```
=average(query(Data!$A$1:$H$136,"select C, A where A > date '"&text(K2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&text(L2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1))
```

But it didn't return anything

Ideally I want to take the average score for all scores in each month

Comment: What excel are you using that has `query`?

Answer (score 1):

Use AVERAGEIFS()

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!$C:$C,Data!$A:$A,">" & K2,Data!$A:$A,"<=" & l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To match your data, and assuming you mean Google Sheets, the query should have been:

```
=average(query(Data!$A$1:$H$136,"select B where A > date '"&text(K2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&text(L2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1))
```

also assuming K2 contains the start of the month and L2 contains the end of the month.

But I believe that @Scott Craner's solution works in both Google Sheets and recent versions of Excel.